# Could a species of Obligate Carnivores achieve sapience?

Tags: science-based, society, species, sapience, carnivorous

So I had this idea for a sort of Speculative Evolution/sci-fi project where humanity(known as the Founders) found no life beyond their solar system and decided to terra-form various planets with life from earth and then one day just vanished without any clue as to how or why. On one of these worlds, the descendants of Raccoons would fill a variety of different predatory niches, with one of its more social descendants achieving sapience in their evolutionary line and creating their own civilization among others from different worlds.

I had a general idea for their appearance with sabre-teeth and thumb-claws and even a sort of spartan/viking like culture for them. However, I've had some people tell me that it would be unlikely for sapience to occur in any carnivorous species due to evolutionary pressures that drove human sapience not being present in any carnivorous species like facing both competition and predation at the same time as well as the fact that once a predator has evolved sufficient biological features for predation, they have no need to develop tools and thus their intelligence would never reach the level of intellect that is possessed by humans, and that it is even less likely for civilization to develop without agriculture which would involve growing plants which my sapient carnivores would not be able to consume. So right now, I don't know what to do. So, is it still possible for predators to achieve sapience?

Comment: Remember that as a worldbuilder you can make anything happen. So if you want your world to have obligate carnivores achieve sapience then that's what happened in your world. What barrier to achieving sapience have you chosen to impose on yourself?

Comment: In terms of the spec evo in my worldbuilding, I'm just trying to make most of it evolutionarily plausible.

Comment: Given the range of life that has evolved on earth what makes you think that it would be implausible besides "some people [told] you"?

Comment: They backed it up with some pretty good explanations. They emphasized that the fact humans became sapient was not only because of competition with other predators, but we ourselves were preyed upon by those same predators which adds evolutionary pressures that would not be experienced by say some hypercarnivore raccoon that eats meat from giant terrestrial flying foxes on a daily basis.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your concerns into the question. That being said: there are plenty of predators that are prey to other predators. if you think that is what leads to evolving sapience then there should be many more sapient species.

Comment: Please put an explicit question in the main post. Even if it is just a repeat of the title question.

Comment: Why would a hypercarnivore raccoon not be preyed upon by larger carnivores?  There are many smaller carnivores that must also avoid being eaten by their own predators.

Comment: Obligate carnivores can be very intelligent even if they don't have their own agriculture and don't use tools. All they have to do is be smart enough to domesticate and enslave some tool using agrarian creatures. I'd provide more details, but my feline supervisors demand that I prepare snacks for them and then clean their litterboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Evolution Requires Pressure:

**To evolve intelligence, what you need is a selective pressure to increase intelligence. If you want tool use, then you need a selective pressure for tool use. The two can easily go hand-in-hand** (play on words intended). **Just create a scenario that explains the pressure.** Climate change is the most common.

So perhaps your carnivores evolved in a warm climate eating small prey. The prey are fairly smart, and tough to catch. Social hunting strategies are needed to catch them, and sharing is needed because the drivers aren't the catchers. Many animals use simple tools (leaves, sticks, rocks) and they use sticks to extract ants, rocks to crack shellfish (by coastlines) and so forth. They lean out on logs and branches to catch fish. But the hunting is still the primary source of food.

Now the climate begins to change. The herbivores that move in are larger and operate in herds. Now these folks struggle to get enough food. Large predators follow these herds and eat most of the prey animals your folks used to eat. So branches are deliberately lowered into the water to make more fishing spots. Someone notices a herbivore falling into an overgrown pit and deliberately covers up the pit again to catch another. The coastal members who use rocks to pound shells now use rocks to pound big herbivores. The natural weapons are still useful, but won't do the job.

One on a branch fishing has the branch break off and sails downriver. There he reaches a sea and once out of the river, paddles his branch to shore - after catching a fish. The local tribe sees him do this, and adopts him (and his paddling logs into the ocean to catch fish).

**The tribes smart enough or adaptive enough to respond to changing conditions, and to communicate these adaptations to other members (and other tribes) do better. The others starve.**

Better tools are developed, herding and animal husbandry develop, agriculture supplies the feed for domesticated animals where they can't move all the time, and suddenly you have an agricultural revolution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't think the concerns you've listed are that much of a problem for raccoons. To begin with, they are omnivores rather than carnivores.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raccoon#Diet)

> Its diet consists of about 40% invertebrates, 33% plant material and 27% vertebrates.[146] Since its diet consists of such a variety of different foods, Zeveloff argues the raccoon "may well be one of the world's most omnivorous animals".

There are plenty of species that prey on raccoons too - for example [this](https://pestpointers.com/animal-predators-that-eat-raccoons-in-depth-look/)

Raccoons are also known for a high degree of intelligence, so not a terrible choice of species for achieving sapience. The biggest problem I think is going to be the fact that raccoons are not very social animals. I think for the complex behaviors needed for sapience you need to be a very social species. However your raccoons could have evolved to be more social along the path to sapience.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Criticism**

If someone says "your world doesn't work because of X" and you believe them, you can always add X into your world so it works.

> The reason Humans became sapient was not only because of competition with other predators, but we ourselves were preyed upon by those same predators

and I will add:

> Apes that live in large groups have bigger brains. It stands to reason being social was a key factor in humans becoming sapient. This would not happen for large solitary predators.

If you believe any of the above advice -- then make it true for your carnivore people. Put them in  groups and give them predators and competition.

Hyaenas are carnivores. They live in a group. They are eaten by and compete with Lions.

Lions are carnivores.  They live in a group.  They are eaten by and compete with Hyaenas.

Sea Otters are carnivores.  They live in a group. They are eaten by and compete with Sharks and killer whales.

Giant Otters are carnivores.  They live in a group. They are eaten by and compete with alligators.

Maybe in your world:

Giant carnivorous racoons are carnivores.  They live in a group. They are eaten by and compete with giant carnivorous opossums.

Answer (score -1):

Ignore them.

Main problem for carnivores is their problems in ability to cooperate, many of those, are territorial creatures(bigger ones, and for that reason), and many do not form groups, but there is enough examples when they do form groups(land and sea) so it possible for them to develop as groups.

Agroculture thing is is a development which is quite late in time, and compared to nomads it does not give advantage for quite some time - nor in power, nor in technologies. Nomads, and heard growing approach was quite sucesseful for until last half thousand years, and it just lately for last half thousand year that settlers did get upper hand compared to nomads. And compare it for at least few million years it took to get there - it not a decidig factor.

Omnivores have higher chances to survive changes, as they can shift their dietary habits more to any side, depending on what's availabe atm, and there were times when our ancestors were predominantly carnivores. So omnivores, carnivores or plant eaters - is not necessarly a deciding factor, and not that human ancestors were born omnivores, they became it as result of number of shifts.

Ability to form groups and using tools is what get us where we are today, in this order. And necessity drived the process, and luck that we didn't die out in the process.

Raccoons do have a chance. Over a long time and across spicies intelligence is given, but for a specific species is just a chance and most likely not for original one but for some of the branches.

#### P.S.

I can't clarify it in comments(due java script incompatibility with my browser), but it looks like it requires some commenting.

- *"Main problem for carnivores is their problems in ability to cooperate"  You say what?!  Carnivores have (and always will have) more reasons to be cooperative than herbivores, when your food fights back or actively attempts to avoid you cooperation becomes a major advantage, they also cooperate to hold territory from others, you've never heard of wolf packs or lion prides?  but you have heard of cooperative bands of rabbits ganging up together to bring down that hard to catch grass?  as a class carnivores have a greater tendency to more complex cooperative behaviours than herbivores.* – @Pelinore

There is a list of mammal carnivores, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carnivorans , about 290 species. I do not know them all, but I would say - I can say are the group or not ones for about a half or more of them.

Out of them canine packs, leons, hyenas are notorious, sea leons as well. I would not call pride to be a pack, but it sure a group and I meant those as examples when they do actually form groups and do cooperate (which is a good stuff for op).

But it needs to understand the reason why 5-tonne animals like elephant (which btw are inelligent, social, group animal) can roam savanna in group of hundreds heads, while bear size carnivores have difficulties and do not and aren't ovligatory carnivores. It all about food, how much productive a territory is, at producing the type of food one needs. Carnivores are secondary consuments, so they need access for a bigger territory for feed themselfs(rough 5x at the same mass). It depends on situation, size and other specifics - but it is one of the evolution pressures which have to be recognised. And it is reflected in distributions, percentages of group and non group species amongth carnivores, herbivores and ominvores. It a pressure, but not a hard rule. It does not work for sea leons as an example, they have 3d hunting ground and other factors which affect them being loose groups.

I mean it wasn't such an ignorant and pointless statement which can be easly brushed off, especialy if we consider a question - can high intellgence deveop in carnivores or not. But it could be a reason for those ppl op mentiont to brush carnivores off, which is not rigth in my opinion based on observable data.

(Not shure why racoons there as carnivores, as they are omnivores, and everything fine for them in this aspect, few global shifts, warimings and they fly in space in 20kk years, lol))

There is anoter reason why carnivres can be considered as less likely to produce high viking intelligence. A sucessefull carnivore is an alpha predator in their nishe and thus have less need or drive for change. I mean there are legit reasons to say carnivores have lesser chances, but canines are one of good example where things are balanced well enough.

### P.P.S.

Rabbits do live in big groups btw. They from groups not to beat grass, but as hedge against predators. They have to be smart, skillfull and adorable to survive)))

### P.P.P.S

- nevermore

Yes, just hanging in a floc (it more direction of swarm intelligence, and there are decent results shown by insects) is not enough, just being cooperative in narrow few goals is not enough. Society, interaction as individuals, recognising/distinguish members as individuals, have likes and dislikes thorwards specific members of own group(that dunbar number) etc etc is a path which produces infinite complexity of interaction, it always deliver more and more of the complexity, it always a challenge and one can't be smart enough to outsmart all the challenges. In that sense society, replaces evolution, becomes evolution jnside of evolution. Society and their potencial precursors flocs, swarms, prides, cooperative groups, loose groups - all those probably may become or transit to a next step on that society path, starting that evolution in evolution. Each of those precursor has its own problems to overcome, and should have sufficient pressure and luck to barge at that next stage. But I think it safe to say one has to have some form of a group, to have a chance to form some sort of society - which is not only about herarchy, but roles, specialisation, sense of belonging, sacrifices, etc etc. Those all can be in their rudimentary form, emerge over time and develop over time.

Society also not enough, so as tools - we had at least 5+ different human like intelligence societies/groups (all those prehistoric humans) they all did fail, and with traces of their blood our kind emerged.

I mean evolution of intelligence on its own is a hell of a lot of a subject, and antropology is very interesting science. My answer was not an attempt to bring all the complexity of it, but just support OP in his perception that Racoons do have a chance - and based on what I know they do (carnivore or omnivore version of them - does not matter that much). At least for a story it has sufficient believeability.

I would not say that gaining high intelligence has some fixed road, and even that argument that alpha predators and no drive for further development is an obstacle for it - I would not buy it that easily. Have seen story (national geografics or something) when pack of wolves learned to racketeer food from bears, so as it took few climate changes to force our ancestors down from trees and further move on the road, so as it can (a different set of changes) move carnivores, who are luky and capable.

- I mean that despite species which predated our human lineage were not alpha predators, they were quite comphy up there. And if one observes monkeys interaction with other species it can be seen why - they are agile and smart and risky enough to smoke most of the creatures in their area. Catching tiger by the tail - would not be surprised they do that to play and annoy the thing. They sure like to do so to smaller animals))

Also I would not like it to be so trivial just about who has hands and who does not - while for sure an ability to manipulate freely available object around oneself it makes a huge difference, but if we embark on what's possible then boiling it all just to such difference is a bit too narrow minded. I mean hard to overvalue hands and alike, but it means more than it says on one hand, but excludes a lot as well if one takes it for face value. So it would be a correct but also it is a misleading statement, misleading because it a correct oversimplification of a more complex subject.(as is, won't dive in it further)

All that is way too deep, and hours upon hours discussions just for basics, and it is above of what OP needs in the case, and more than I'm willing to spend my time on. If not racoons I would not even bother.

Comment: *"Main problem for carnivores is their problems in ability to cooperate"*  You say what?!  Carnivores have (and always will have) more reasons to be cooperative than herbivores, when your food fights back or actively attempts to avoid you cooperation becomes a major advantage, they also cooperate to hold territory from others, you've never heard of wolf packs or lion prides?  but you have heard of cooperative bands of rabbits ganging up together to bring down that hard to catch grass?  as a class carnivores have a greater tendency to more complex cooperative behaviours than herbivores.

Comment: Hmm .. In response to the clarification in your answer: Personally I would say simply hanging out together in flocks or herds as many herbivores do, though a social behaviour, isn't a complex cooperative behaviour, just a difference in perspective perhaps, but I don't think that counts, elephants clearly do have good cooperative behaviours though, but they're beyond the norm for obligate herbivores in that I feel, thing is now in think of it social behaviour (not the same thing as cooperative) has often been cited as a primary path to intelligence.

Comment: *"not the same thing as cooperative"* cooperative is a subset of social behaviour yes, but the social behaviours most often cited isn't cooperative, it's more normally that associated with larger groups, that associated with dominance hierarchies and such associated with larger groups & the proto communication arising from that.

Comment: Downvote.  Carnivores don't cooperate? Wolves? Dolphins? Whales? Lions? Across the animal kingdom, without exception, predators are smarter than their prey. It requires a large brain and proper thinking to outsmart and eat an herbivore. Conversely, it doesn't take much brainpower to eat grass. There is clearly an overwhelming amount of evidence that shows humans reached their level of intelligence only because of meat consumption. It's better for large brains because meat is far more nutrient dense and efficient. Do the math. How much meat do you need to eat vs how much grass to run a brain?

Answer (score -1):

I would be inclined to agree with that person.

For starters, there are a number of unique evolutionary pressures and fuels that launched humanity's sapience. I will start with adding some to the things your critic has already pointed out.

Firstly it is not just the fact that humans had to compete with/were preyed upon by other predators, it's the fact that we ourselves had **no** previous adaptations for predation. No specialized teeth, no specialized claws. This fueled the development of tools to help us kill our prey. You describe your species as having such adaptations for predation, in that case, why would such a species even bother with tools? Why waste energy making a spear when you can kill things just as, if not, more effectively by using your own teeth and claws? Second, in addition to competing with other predators, with being preyed upon, you have that pressure to find ways of defending yourself. We had no way of defending ourselves until someone came up with the idea of living in houses and using the tools we used for hunting as a means of defense, which once again, **your species would not have needed to develop in the first place if they have their own natural weapons**.

Second, there are nutritional requirements for a brain of human-level intellect that would not be met with the diet of something that exclusively eats meat. Meat may be more nutrient dense than other food sources, but it is the kind of nutrient that matters. And there are several key nutrients for the brain, none of which are found in animal-based food sources. For human intelligence we get our key nutrients from vegetables such as kale, spinach, and broccoli, as well as a variety of nuts and berries. Notice that meat is **not** one of these sources.

Thirdly, I'm going to go through a list of animals on earth that come close to human intelligence and tell you what they eat. Crows, they are omnivores. Parrots, they are omnivores. The great apes, chimps, gorillas, and bonobos, all of them are omnivores. The raccoons that you say this species is descended from are omnivores. Elephants? herbivores, actually. "*But what about toothed whales, and cephalopods?*" some may ask. Well, I'd like to include them, but the truth is, given how different the ecology of the oceans are to the ecologies of the land, they don't count, since on some level nearly everything eats some kind of meat in the oceans. Notice that **none** of the animals I have listed here are **obligate carnivores**. Wouldn't one think of this as kind of telling? Yes, wolves, and some felids may have a degree of intellect, but when you look at things objectively, they are no more intelligent than a one-and-a-half-year-old human and have no pressures to develop that further, whereas the animals I have listed have at least the intellect of a five-year-old human child and do have some pressures to take that further.

This leads me to conclude that the idea of a predatory species that is an obligate carnivore may sound cool on paper, but in reality is extremely unlikely if not, impossible. Maybe you can have a species of relatively intelligent carnivores, but make them as intelligent as a two-year-old at best if you want accuracy.

Answer (score -1):

/once a predator has evolved sufficient biological features for predation, they have no need to develop tools and thus their intelligence would never reach the level of intellect that is possessed by humans/

**Intelligence is sexy.**

[image]

https://www.wired.com/2016/02/absurd-creature-of-the-week-meet-the-bird-that-lies-and-tricks-its-way-into-sex/

Your pack hunters do not need more to effectively pack hunt.  They are already the best.  But among these hunters, female preference for intelligent males have led to an intelligence arms race.  This is what has happened with the bowerbird.  Theirs is intelligence in the service of beauty, display and artifice.  The most spectacular gets to reproduce.

So too your creatures.  Their intelligence is unmoored from any practical application.  It is intelligence for the sake of intelligence.  But as opposed to the bowerbird which is a small frugivore, this intelligence starts with a carnivorous pack hunter.  The methods by which your intelligent carnivores display their goods are amazing, creative and terrible.

---

Comment: Downvotes?  Is this not good?  I thought it was a cool premise.

Comment: I don't know. Like one commenter pointed out, there are still nutritional requirements.

Comment: The tailfeathers of a peacock require an enormous amount of resources and are incredibly impractical.  Other than attracting a mate, the feathers are a significant detriment to survival.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - I like the idea of intelligence as tailfeathers - competing males who are so intelligent it is a detriment to their survival.   What a fine premise for a SF!